# Do until sheet loop with exclusion

Tags: excel, vba

In the below , the macro will loop till the sheet "XYZ". There are 10 sheets before the sheet "XYZ".

In those 10 sheets i dont want the macro to run on sheet "XBA" and sheet "XBZ".

Please help. I am unable to find exact vba code for this kind of a loop.

```
Sub Fexp1()
Sheets("AAA").Activate
i = 4
Do Until ActiveSheet.Name = "XYZ"
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    sh.Range("$A7:$M7").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="x1"

    Rowz = sh.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
    If Rowz <> 0 Then

    Dim rTable As Range
    Set rTable = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    Set rTable = rTable.Resize(rTable.Rows.Count - 1)
    Set rTable = rTable.Offset(1)
    rTable.Copy
    Sheets("EXP1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
End If
  Sheets(i + 1).Activate
  i = i + 1
  
Loop
Sheets("EXP1").Select
  Columns("F:F").Select
    Range("F2").Activate
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> In those 10 sheets i dont want the macro to run on sheet "XBA" and sheet "XBZ".

I would recommned using a `For` Loop with `Select Case`. It will be easier to handle

Here is an example to achieve what you want.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
    Case "XBA", "XBZ"
        '~~> Do nothing
    Case Else
        '~~> Do what you want here
    End Select
Next ws
```

Also avoid the use of `.Select`. You may want to read up on [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Here is an example. The below lines

```
Sheets("EXP1").Select
Columns("F:F").Select
Range("F2").Activate
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

can also be written as

```
Sheets("EXP1").Columns(6).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Comment: I've just done exactly that, hence I've deleted my comment. Your code doesn't activate F2 however.

Comment: @JMP: Thats the point. No need to activate F2. I think the code came there because user was recording a macro.

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks for the advise. But this method is not working. In this method the macro is running only in the 1st sheet and once it finishes it is not switching to second sheet , instead it is running the macro in Sheet EXP1. Ideally it should run in 2 sheet (ABA) after 1 sheet (AAA).

Comment: It is not possible that this method will not work. It **WILL** loop though all worksheets and skip "XBA" and "XBZ". Can you post the code that you now have. I feel that you are doing something wrong. @vignesh95

Comment: Check it out in this "https://www.appdevtools.com/pastebin/hSYLXz"

Comment: `If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False` Do not use activesheet. What is th epoing of the loop then. change it to `ws.AutoFilterMode` and so on